# Pandas: Aggregating lists in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
   VehID   Material  JobNo
0  10000      5005  [1, 2]
1  10000      5100  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
2  10001      5222  [2, 3, 4]
3  10001      5888  [1, 3]
```

I would like to pull out instances where the list elements in 'JobNo' occurs in a consecutive fashion. For eg:

```
   VehID  Material   JobNo     Len
0  10000      5005  [1, 2]      2
1  10000      5100  [1, 2]      2
2  10000      5100  [5, 6]      2
3  10001      5222  [2, 3, 4]   3
```

Does anyone have a neat solution to this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use `numpy.diff`, `numpy.split` to break up lists where non-contigous

```
def split_jobs(x):
    return np.split(x, np.where(np.append(False, np.diff(x) != 1))[0])

j = df.JobNo.apply(split_jobs)
l1 = j.str.len()

slc = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(l1)
d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        VehID=df.VehID.values[slc],
        Material=df.Material.values[slc],
        JobNo=list(chain(*j.tolist()))
    ))[df.columns.tolist()]

d1[d1.JobNo.str.len() > 1]

   VehID  Material      JobNo
0  10000      5005     [1, 2]
1  10000      5100     [1, 2]
2  10000      5100  [4, 5, 6]
3  10001      5222  [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Your answer works well, with a slight modification to 'np.arange(len(df)).repeat(l1)'. Else the program throws the following error: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'